# How to cache my tag_counts for acts_as_taggable_on.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have this in an erb file>

```
<%= select_tag :catalog_item_submission_tag, options_for_select(Submission.tag_counts.order('name ASC').map {|t| [t.name, t.name]}, params[:catalog_item_submission_tag]), include_blank: true, class: 'select2ify allow-clear' %>
```

and I'd like to cache it because the tag counts are huge and are costing my site time:

```
Submission.tag_counts.count
 => 23399
```

And they don't change that often (maybe a cache that expires once every 4 hours is sufficient). Is there a way to do this using the `acts_as_taggable_on` gem?

For reference, the `submission` has tags:

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick

  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
```

Comment: Did you check this: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/wiki/Caching

Comment: so I don't really get it... when does the cache expire? @luisenrike

Comment: Say I didn't want all the new tags immediately... is there a way to set the cache to expire every 4 hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to wrap your code in `Rails.cache.fetch`, like that:

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick

  acts_as_taggable_on :tags

  def self.cashed_tags_counts
    Rails.cache.fetch("cashed_tags", expires_in: 4.hours) do
      tag_counts.order('name ASC').map {|t| [t.name, t.name]}
    end
  end
end
```

[Here is more information about it](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching)

Comment: In this post: github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/wiki/Caching, how does that caching work?

Comment: Seems like it create string field `cached_category_list` in Product model that store tags for each product in this field. So when you call `product.category_list` - you get tags from product.cached_category_list instead of tags table.